# create json encoded data from php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get this format in my jSON output but cant seem to figure out how to get the formatting down.

```
{
"total": 20,
"result": [
    {
        "image": "http://test.com/images/001.jpg",
        "width": 192,
        "height": 288
    },
    {
        "image": "http://test.com/images/001.jpg",
        "width": 192,
        "height": 257
    },
    {
        "image": "http://test.com/images/001.jpg",
        "width": 192,
        "height": 288
    },
    {
        "image": "http://test.com/images/001.jpg",
        "width": 192,
        "height": 288
    }
]
}
```

I was able to do this which doesnt include the total:

```
$json['result'][] = array('image' => 'http://www.google.com', 'width' => '120', 'height' => '200');
json_encode($json);
```

My end goal is to be able to create the json output from this database call:

```
$objDB = new DB;
    $submissions = $objDB
    ->setStoredProc( 'petContestFetchImages' )
    ->setParam("offset", $offset )
    ->setParam("rows", $limit )
    ->execStoredProc()
    ->parseXML(); 

    //$link = $submissions->link; 
    //$width = $submissions->width;
    //$heigth = $submissions->height; 
    //$total = $submissions->total;
```

**EDIT**

This is my database attempt however the jSON response seems off..

```
//Fetch Entries
$objDB = new DB;
    $submissions = $objDB
    ->setStoredProc( 'petContestFetchImages' )
    ->setParam("offset", $offset )
    ->setParam("rows", $limit )
    ->execStoredProc()
    ->parseXML();     

//Total
$json['total'] = $submissions->total;   

//Loop over the result set and store it as jSON
foreach($submissions->submission as $submission) { 

    $json['result'][] = array('petName' => $submission->petName, 'petCaption' => $submission->petCaption, 'imageName' => $submission->imageName);   

}

//Output the result
print json_encode($json);
```

Output:

```
{

   "total": 20,

   "result": [

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Nala"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "nalaHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Simba"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "simbaHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "BoBo"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "boboHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Frank"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "frankHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Jim"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "frankHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Sasha"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "boboHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Sam"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "simbaHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Alice"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "nalaHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Sara"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "boboHUS123.png"

         }

      },

      {

         "petName": {

            "0": "Judy"

         },

         "petCaption": {

            "0": "Shes a wonder pup!"

         },

         "imageName": {

            "0": "nalaHUS123.png"

         }

      }

   ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an array witch holds total string, and a result array,

```
$json[] = array('image' => 'http://www.google.com', 'width' => '120', 'height' => '200');
$result = array('total'=>20,'result'=>$json);

json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json['total'] = 20;
$json['result'][] = array('image' => 'http://www.google.com', 'width' => '120', 'height' => '200');
json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

First fetch data from the DB. This will may not output exactly you require JSON but this will give you solution.

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$result[] = array('image'=>$row['image'],'height',=>$row['height'],'width'=>$row['width']);
}
$data =  array( 'total'=>count($result),'result'=>$result);
json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I tried something similar however the output is slightly off. Made addition to original post